# keyError on newline when format multi-lines string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format, quote

```
print("xy{0}z".format(100))
xy100z
```

Let's try  string with multi-lines.
The string i want to format it.

```
strs='''  
.item{0}{  
    background-image:url("img/item{0}_1.jpg");  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-position: 0px 0px;  
}'''  

>>> print(strs)

.item{0}{
    background-image:url("img/item{0}_1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Now to format it with some number.

```
print(strs.format(100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '\n    background-image'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `{` with `{{` / `}` with `}}` to mean `{`/`}` literally.

```
strs='''
.item{0}{{
    background-image:url("img/item{0}_1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}}'''  
print(strs.format(100))
```

prints:

```
.item100{
    background-image:url("img/item100_1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```